# Widget is shown as 0x0 and crashes Launcher

Tags: android, widget, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

So, I have declared a widget for my app and wanted to try it on the Ice Cream Sandwich emulator, however when I select it, it crashes the launcher.

The problem is, that the launcher thinks width and heigt would equal 0 (it also lists my widget as a 0x0 widget), so I guess there is a problem in my declaration

```
E/AndroidRuntime(  709): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
E/AndroidRuntime(  709):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:603)
E/AndroidRuntime(  709):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:585)
[...]
```

This is my widget declaration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   android:updatePeriodMillis="7200000" 
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:minHeight="72dp" android:minWidth="90dp"> 
</appwidget-provider>
```

Is there something wrong with `minHeight` and `minWidth`?

Comment: I don't think the error is related to your appwidget-provider xml file. From the logcat, this error should be related to a Bitmap object. Did you create a Bitmap object?

Comment: Yes, actually I use a PNG picture load from the ressources. I edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I just noticed, that there is a ">" aftter the xmlns:android, maybe it works without...

Comment: Yes, you should delete that `>`. I'm surprised it even compiles this way!

Comment: Yes, that was the reason for the crash! I am very surprised as well :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone made the same mistake: This was due to a syntax error (see comments above) the compiler didn't recognize.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way to trigger the same error is to set `android:previewImage` to a dimensionless shape drawable in the `my_widget_info.xml` file and not to a png.

Solved by setting `android:previewImage` to a drawable with dimensions, for example any .png.

At first I thought it would be clever to use the background shape drawable as a placeholder preview image while working on my widget, which is why I got this error.